Sharing Clipboard Between Weston and Xorg
I’ve installed the wl-clipboard package and tried copying text from Xorg to a Weston window, but I encountered the following error:
[hemlo@ASUS ~]$   whoami
reyuki
[hemlo@ASUS ~]$    wl-copy "hellow world"
Failed to connect to a Wayland server: Connection refused
Note: WAYLAND_DISPLAY is set to /run/user/1000/
Note: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is set to /run/user/1000/wayland-1
[hemlo@ASUS ~]$  ls -l /run/user/1000/wayland-1
srwxr-xr-x 1 reyuki reyuki 0 Aug 24 21:23 /run/user/1000/wayland-1
[hemlo@ASUS ~]$  file /run/user/1000/wayland-1
/run/user/1000/wayland-1: socket

Why am I getting a "connection refused" error? What is the correct way to share the clipboard between Weston and Xorg?
I found similar questions on the internet, but there doesn’t seem to be an answer yet:

reddit
superuser


Somehow I accidentally invert the value of WAYLAND_DISPLAY and XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
I managed to get it working by set WAYLAND_DISPLAY to proper socket file on /run/user/1000:
$ WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1 wl-copy "test"

